# Nuclear attack followed by a ground invasion

Tags: plot-explanation, dune-part-two

In the sequel to the movie *Dune* (2021), i.e. *Dune: Part Two* (2024), Timothée Chalamet’s character, Paul “Muad’Dib” Atreides reveals the secret locations of his family’s arsenal of nuclear weapons to the Fremen:

[image: Stockpile of House Atreides’ atomics]

Not long after this, we see bombs going off in the Emperor’s city (Arrakeen) — presumably these are the nukes:

[image: Silhouette of Paul “Muad'Dib” Atreides watching a nuclear blast going off in Arrakeen]

The Battle of Arrakeen continues shortly after this, with Paul Atreides leading the Fremen to make a direct assault, seizing the city and confronting the Emperor.

But no one seems to be fazed by the fact that the city has just been hit with nukes.

---

I can’t understand how it could possibly make any sense to invade a place that has been nuked like this. Nuclear weapons are known to be bad for one’s health, and the lethal effects of the radiation and fallout ought to linger for years to come.

**How can anyone in the city survive, not just the initial blast, but also the ongoing nuclear radiation?**

Comment: Nuclear weapons are not as damaging as you may think. There are accounts of some surviving the Hiroshima bombing at a distance of less than 300 m from the epicentre and most people in the city suffered no ill effects from the radiation.

Comment: Agreed, we know nothing of the *Dune* devices but Hiroshima's *Little Boy* device had a "small" yield of 12-15 *kilo*tons. Nothing like the megatonnage devices that would follow in the later years.

Comment: The Atreides nuclear weapons were not a secret. All of the great houses had nuclear weapons and everyone knew it. There was a very serious law, the great convention that meant that any house who used nuclear weapons against peoole would be destroyed by the other houses. Which is why they only used such weapons against the shield wall, not against people.

Comment: @JudithJones I’ve fixed that sentence by changing “secret arsenal” to “secret location of …“.

Comment: Related question (on SF&F): [Where was the Shield Wall brought down?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255758/where-was-the-shield-wall-brought-down)

Comment: @Valorum A few fleas, rats etc also survived, but reportedly between [129,000 and 226,000 people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki) died. Not sure how that classifies as "not so destructive." The dust generated by a nuclear blast is [nasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_testing_at_Bikini_Atoll#Japanese_fishermen_contaminated).

Comment: Just for the record: "Less than a second after the detonation, the north of the city [Nagasaki] was destroyed and more than 10% of the city's population were killed.[26] Among the 35,000 deaths ..." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagasaki#Atomic_bombing_of_Nagasaki_during_World_War_II)). The Nagasaki explosion was the *less* deadly of the blasts.

Comment: @BuckThorn - There are vast discrepancies in the death counts, ranging from a few tens of thousands up to nearly half a million, depending on who you listen to and what you count as a related death. Suffice to say, a nuclear explosion even a few tens of miles away from the city would result in almost no *direct* casualties (indeed, Paul is counting on this) and almost no indirect casualties.

Comment: @JudithJones - That the Atreides still had access to their nukes was a big surprise to The Emperor and the Harkonnen. They thought that their strike was rapid enough to prevent retaliation

Comment: @Valorum Granted, the [numbers for Nagasaki suggest as much](https://www.atomicarchive.com/resources/documents/med/med_chp10.html). Felt it nonetheless important not to suggest that a 1 in 10 chance of surviving a hit within a click of ground zero is a good deal.

Comment: Some types of atomic weapons produce less radiation than others.  I could believe that it wasn't infeasible to use small fusion bombs in an attack.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The atomics are not used on the city, they are used on the natural shield wall that protects the city for the majority of the effects of storms and sandworms.

Paul uses the atomics to penetrate the shield wall and allow the worms into the area of the city.

> ‘The in­junc­tion!’ Paul barked. ‘It’s fear, not the in­junc­tion that keeps the Houses from hurl­ing atom­ics against each other. The lan­guage of the Great Con­ven­tion is clear enough: “Use of atom­ics against hu­mans shall be cause for plan­e­tary oblit­er­a­tion.” **We’re go­ing to blast the Shield Wall, not hu­mans.'**
>
> <sup>*Dune* - Frank Herbert</sup>

From my research it *appears* that the Shield Wall breach was c.100km from Arrakeen which is plenty of distance so that the city would not be affected unduly.

[This question at SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255758/where-was-the-shield-wall-brought-down) asks where the Shield Wall was breached and the answer would appear to be at the Rimwall West (ringed in red below)

[image]

This map indicates (from the scale legend) that Arrakeen is c.100km from that section.

[image]

Radiation is still a concern (it's mentioned in the book) but again, the atomics were used in the desert some distance from the city. I'd suggest you look at the history of Nevada desert testing near Las Vegas. This was often done 50-60 miles (an equivalent distance) from the city.

[image]

Comment: So the character in the silhouette imagine in my question would have to be [standing on that rocky peninsula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKhst.png) that extends behind Arrakeen, looking across the city, with the Shield Wall being bombed far in the distance.

Answer (score 11):

According to the follow-up novel (set shortly after the events of Dune), radiation continues to be a problem at ground zero, causing harm to those living nearby.

> Finally Stilgar received a message from a poor desert family that
> lived in one of the squalid villages at the fringe of the Shield Wall,
> where breezes blew sand into the sheltered basin and radiation from
> Muad’Dib’s atomics still lingered at barely tolerable levels. Children
> were often seen playing at the edge of the desert. This family had
> reported noticing two girls that they did not recognize.
>
> <sub><sup>[Paul of Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_of_Dune)</sup></sub>